# How to dynamically change template of popover in angular-strap

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-strap

I am using angularstrap to create a popover using a template. I am using the attribute ng-attr-data-template to provide link to the template. I am changing the mentioned attribute value using a function which is called on click of a button.
But the change is not being reflected to the popover. Please suggest the possible solution for this problem.

Here is the link to [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/pm53zPJILqEfnazyMzB1)
Code is as follows

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="klk">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js" data-semver="v2.0.4"></script>
  <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.0.4"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <hr/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  placement="right" data-animation="am-flip-x" 
  ng-attr-data-template="{{link}}"  data-auto-close="1" bs-popover >
                        {{link}}
    </button>
    <hr/>
  <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click = "changeContent()">Change link</button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('klk', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $popover){
 $scope.trackName = 'Click on the button and give us a name';
 $scope.popov = function(el){
     $popover(angular.element(el),
        {
            show: true,
            placement: 'right',
            template: 'link1.html',
            animation: 'am-flip-x'
        });
 };
$scope.link = "link1.html";
$scope.change = true;
  $scope.changeContent = function(){
    $scope.change = !$scope.change;
    if ($scope.change)
      $scope.link = "link1.html";
    else
      $scope.link = "link2.html";
}
});
```

link1.html

```
<div class="popover">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title"><strong>Heading 1</strong></h3>
  <div class="popover-content">

    pop content 1

  </div>
</div>
```

link2.html

```
<div class="popover" >
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title"><strong>Heading 2</strong></h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
       pop content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in changing the content of the template dynamically, it can be accomplished by using the following way.
Here is an example of modified Index.html. Notice that there is a data-content and a data-title that bound to model properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="klk">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js" data-semver="v2.0.4"></script>
  <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.0.4"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <hr/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  placement="right" data-animation="am-flip-x"   data-title = "{{popover.title}}" data-content="{{popover.content}}" data-template="link3.html"  data-auto-close="1" bs-popover >Click Me</button>
<hr/>
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click = "changeContent()">Change   link</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the module and the controller, In this controller we have a model called popover with the properties title and content, this will be dynamic. For example, if you called the function changeContent it will toggle the content and make the content in popover change.
// Code goes here
    var app = angular.module('klk', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $popover){
$scope.trackName = 'Click on the button and give us a name';
$scope.toggleContent=true;
$scope.popover = {
    "title": "Original Content",
    "content": "loading...",
};

$scope.changeContent=function(){
if($scope.toggleContent){
     $scope.popover = {
       "title": "Changed",
       "content": "<p>hello the content has changed!</p>",
      };

}else{
// show original content
 $scope.popover = {
    "title": "Original Content",
    "content": "Hello Content 1...",
   };
  }
 }

});
```

Here is a template that will have the content and the title that will be dynamic as it is bound to model properties title and content. Look for ng-bind-html

```
<div class="popover" tabindex="-1" ng-show="content">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="popover-title" ng-bind-html="title"></div>
<div class="popover-content">
    <form name="popoverForm">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <!--<button class="btn-sm  pull-right close-popover" ng-click="$hide()">x</button>-->
        </div>
        <p ng-bind-html="content" style="min-width:300px;"></p>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

A working example of this can be found here
http://plnkr.co/edit/FpqwcdcPNVI3zIzK6Ut1?p=preview